# ng-model not updating input properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I have this same function on another page and it works beautifully, but for the life of me can't figure out why its not working in a 2nd implemenation:

If the userPhone input starts out blank, and I begin typing a number, all I get is the following over and over.  But why would len.length = 0 the moment I type a number into the input field, technically the length should at least be 1.  I see whats a happening after- $scope.userPhone is being assigned NaN - thus the new length is now 3...but even as I type more numbers, it never changes or updates. $scope[itemID] ($scope.userPhone) properly.

```
len: 0
THere! NaN
len: 3
THere! NaN
len: 3
THere! NaN
```

and if it starts out with a number already in it, and I delete some or add some numbers I get the following:  `len: 10` - over and over.  No matter if the visible length is 0 3, 5 or 15.  Its like $scope.userPhone ($scope[itemID]) is never updating the input field.  Because length is 10, it never makes into the first IF to truncate the length.

HTML

```
  <input type="number" id="userPhone" ng-model="userPhone" ng-change="monitorLength('userPhone',10)" ng-blur="verify('userPhone',10)">
```

JS $scope variables to be created for template:

```
  var regFields = ["userNameFirst","userNameLast","userPhone","userEmail","userAddress1",
          "userAddress2","userCity","userState","userZip","userCountry","userCardType",
          "userCardNumber","userCardMonth","userCardYear","userCardCSV"] ;
```

build $scope vars

```
  var reg = new RegExp(/^\d+$/) ;
  for (var x=0;x<regFields.length;x++) {
    var val = getDB(regFields[x]) ;
    if (reg.test(val)) { // is a number, convert back to data type number
      val = parseInt(val) ;
    }
    console.log("creating $scope: "+regFields[x]+ " w/ value: "+val+ " as "+typeof(val)) ;
    $scope[regFields[x]] = val ;
  }


$scope.monitorLength = function(itemID,maxLength) {
  if ($scope[itemID] != null) {
    var len = $scope[itemID].toString() ;
    console.log("len: "+len.length) ;
    if (len.length > maxLength) {
      $scope[itemID] = parseInt(len.substring(0, maxLength));
      console.log("Here! " + $scope[itemID]) ;
    } else if (!reg.test(len)) {
      $scope[itemID] = parseInt(len.substring(0, len.length-1));
      console.log("THere! " + $scope[itemID]) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Need to provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what is in your scope and have no way to reproduce your issue. You are also breaking the golden rule of not using an object in `ng-model`

Comment: First don't send an itemID but the actual item `ng-change="monitorLength(userPhone, 10)`. Then don't override what's in scope[itemID], but use another variable: `var update = +(String(item).substring(0, maxLength)); console.log(update);`

Comment: @floribon - your method is passing the value of userPhone into the monitorLength function...but once in and the update is provided, how then are you passing the new `update` (if over maxLength) back to the proper $scope variable?

Comment: @rolinger ah indeed, so you can keep what you'r doing. But you should add more logs to understand why you get NaN. What is in `len` when you log its length?

Comment: Also try wrapping what's in your monitorLength function around a $timeout: `$scope.monitorLength = function(itemID,maxLength) { $timeout(function() { ..... }); }`

Comment: @floribon - I understand why i am getting NaN when there is no current number listed.  When I enter the first digit of the phone number "4" that triggeres the ng-change.  'len.length' is reporting 0 (it should be reporting 1), that tells me $scope[itemID] is not "4", its empty thus its getting into the last IF statement, once in its being evaluated as NaN and NaN is being assigned to back to $scope[itemID].  What I don't understand is why when I type next number "43", the same thing happens again...$scope.userPhone is visually "43" but the code continues to evaluate $scope[itemID] as empty.

Comment: @floribon - its like whats being passed back monitorLength('userPhone',10) is not whats actually being evaluated with $scope[itemID], or what $scope[itemID] is being reassigned to isn't the same.  In console.log $scope[itemID] prints out the same thing every time ng-change triggers, yet the <input> field itself shows a different number - thus making me think they aren't the same modals.

Comment: May I know what is that getDB function?

Comment: getDB is a global function for retrieving data from localStorage.  The code included in the above issue though should be in the global function and I am in the process of moving it there now....until this above issue, I hadn't had a need to check for data type, but now I have the need to do so in quite a few locations, thus its going into the global retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, but I don't understand why, maybe someone can explain it to me.

My original $scope variable assignments were as follows, reading data in from localStorage:

```
  var regFields = ["userNameFirst","userNameLast","userPhone","userEmail","userAddress1","userAddress2","userCity","userState","userZip","userCountry",
      "userCardType","userCardNumber","userCardMonth","userCardYear","userCardCSV"] ;
  var reg = new RegExp(/^\d+$/) ;
  for (var x=0;x<regFields.length;x++) {
    var val = getDB(regFields[x]) ;
    if (reg.test(val)) { // is a number, convert back to data type number
      val = parseInt(val) ;
    }
    $scope[regFields[x]] = val ;
  }
```

I then changed it to:

```
  $scope.userObj = {} ;
  var regFields = ["userNameFirst","userNameLast","userPhone","userEmail","userAddress1","userAddress2","userCity","userState","userZip","userCountry",
          "userCardType","userCardNumber","userCardMonth","userCardYear","userCardCSV"] ;
  var userObj = {} ; 
  var reg = new RegExp(/^\d+$/) ;
  for (var x=0;x<regFields.length;x++) {
    var val = getDB(regFields[x]) ;
    if (reg.test(val)) { // is a number, convert back to data type number
      val = parseInt(val) ;
    }
    $scope.userObj[regFields[x]] = val ;
  }
```

and then all my model were changed accordingly:

```
from: ng-model="userPhone" to ng-model="userObj.userPhone"
```

Why does assigning everything within a single $scope.object work versus just creating a unique $scope.var for each key read in from localStorage?

@charlietfl